# How to compile multiple gsoap client webservices into one executable?

Tags: c++, web-services, gsoap

I using `gSOAP` for web services, but i have a problem i must
compile 2 web services into one executable file, and some
functions have same names instead of argument for using
other prefix for function names.

Compilation Error:

```
X.o: In function `soap_get_string(soap*, char**, char const*, char const*)':
X.cpp:8669: multiple definition of `soap_get_string(soap*, char**, char const*, char const*)'
Y.o:Y.cpp:4763: first defined here
```

In Makefile:

```
wsdl2h -qlpr X.wsdl
wsdl2h Y.wsdl Y.xsd
soapcpp2 -qlpr -plpr -plprws $(GSOAP_IMPORT) -i -C X.h
soapcpp2 -psiwcprws $(GSOAP_IMPORT) -i -C Y.h
```

Have anyone idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 19.34  How to Combine Multiple Client and Server Implementations into one Executable The wsdl2h tool can be used to import multiple WSDLs
>   and schemas at once. The service definitions are combined in one
>   header file to be parsed by soapcpp2. It is important to assign
>   namespace prefixes to namespace URIs using the typemap.dat file.
>   Otherwise, wsdl2h will assign namespace prefixes ns1, ns2, and so on
>   to the service operations and schema types. Thus, any change to a WSDL
>   or schema may result in a new prefix assignment. For more details,
>   please see Section 8.2. Another approach to combine multiple client
>   and service applications into one executable is by using C++
>   namespaces to structurally separate the definitions or by creating C
>   libraries for the client/server objects as explained in subsequent
>   sections. This is automated with wsdl2h option -q. Both approaches are
>   demonstrated by example in the gSOAP distribution, the samples/link (C
>   only) and samples/link++ (C++ with C++ namespaces) examples.